# ASP MVC database not showing foreign key attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, foreign-keys

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC application, and recently, one of the tables in my database is no longer displaying its foreign keys, and I cannot for the life of me work out why.  There are other tables in the database that reference the same tables as this one does, and they work just fine, but for some reason, this now shows up as blank.  Other tables use very similar code to this, which is why I'm especially stumped.  I've even tried deleting and re-scaffolding the controller and view, and upon altering `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Ref)` to something like `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product.ProductID)` yields the same problem.

**EDIT:** 
I'm using EF code first, and sadly re-seeding my database doesn't help.  Would it help if I showed my context class?

**SECOND EDIT:** 
I solved the problem, in my context class I was declaring each foreign key as optional, which for some reason meant they didn't show at all.  Upon removing that, everything works fine, now.

Controller Code:

```
        public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
        {
            ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
            ViewBag.IDSortParam = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "ID_desc" : "";
            ViewBag.RefSortParam = sortOrder == "Ref" ? "Ref_desc" : "Ref";
            ViewBag.ProdNameSortParam = sortOrder == "ProdName" ? "ProdName_desc" : "ProdName";
            ViewBag.UnitPriceSortParam = sortOrder == "UnitPrice" ? "UnitPrice_desc" : "UnitPrice";
            ViewBag.FormatSortParam = sortOrder == "Format" ? "Format_desc" : "Format";
            ViewBag.QuantitySortParam = sortOrder == "Quantity" ? "Quantity_desc" : "Quantity";
            ViewBag.AvailabilitySortParam = sortOrder == "Availability" ? "Availability_desc" : "Availability";
            ViewBag.NewSortParam = sortOrder == "New" ? "New_desc" : "New";
            ViewBag.LocationSortParam = sortOrder == "Location" ? "Location_desc" : "Location";
            ViewBag.OrigNoSortParam = sortOrder == "OrigNo" ? "OrigNo_desc" : "OrigNo";
            ViewBag.TitleSortParam = sortOrder == "Title" ? "Title_desc" : "Title";
            ViewBag.ShortTitleSortParam = sortOrder == "ShortTitle" ? "ShortTitle_desc" : "ShortTitle";
            ViewBag.LinkSortParam = sortOrder == "Link" ? "Link_desc" : "Link";
            ViewBag.NotesSortParam = sortOrder == "Notes" ? "Notes_desc" : "Notes";
            ViewBag.Notes2SortParam = sortOrder == "Notes2" ? "Notes2_desc" : "Notes2";
            ViewBag.TypeSortParam = sortOrder == "Type" ? "Type_desc" : "Type";
            ViewBag.SerTitleSortParam = sortOrder == "SerTitle" ? "SerTitle_desc" : "SerTitle";
            ViewBag.SubjectSortParam = sortOrder == "Subject" ? "Subject_desc" : "Subject";
            ViewBag.ClassSubjSortParam = sortOrder == "ClassSubj" ? "ClassSubj_desc" : "ClassSubj";
            ViewBag.ClassGeogSortParam = sortOrder == "ClassGeog" ? "ClassGeog_desc" : "ClassGeog";
            ViewBag.ClassLangSortParam = sortOrder == "ClassLang" ? "ClassLang_desc" : "ClassLang";
            ViewBag.ClassDateSortParam = sortOrder == "ClassDate" ? "ClassDate_desc" : "ClassDate";
            ViewBag.RelName1SortParam = sortOrder == "RelName1" ? "RelName1_desc" : "RelName1";
            ViewBag.RelName2SortParam = sortOrder == "RelName2" ? "RelName2_desc" : "RelName2";
            ViewBag.RelName3SortParam = sortOrder == "RelName3" ? "RelName3_desc" : "RelName3";
            ViewBag.RelName4SortParam = sortOrder == "RelName4" ? "RelName4_desc" : "RelName4";
            ViewBag.RelTit1SortParam = sortOrder == "RelTit1" ? "RelTit1_desc" : "RelTit1";
            ViewBag.RelTit2SortParam = sortOrder == "RelTit2" ? "RelTit2_desc" : "RelTit2";
            ViewBag.RelTit3SortParam = sortOrder == "RelTit3" ? "RelTit3_desc" : "RelTit2";

            if (searchString != null)
            {
                page = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                searchString = currentFilter;
            }

            ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;

            var catalogs = from c in db.Catalogs//.Include(c => c.BicFull).Include(c => c.BicFull2).Include(c => c.BicFull3).Include(c => c.BicFull4).Include(c => c.Product).Include(c => c.RelatedName).Include(c => c.RelatedName2).Include(c => c.RelatedName3).Include(c => c.RelatedName4).Include(c => c.RelatedTitle).Include(c => c.RelatedTitle2).Include(c => c.RelatedTitle3).Include(c => c.RelatedTitle4).Include(c => c.Series)
                           select c;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                catalogs = catalogs.Where(s => s.Ref.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()) ||
                                          s.ProductID.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()) ||
                                          s.Format.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));
            }

            switch (sortOrder)
            {
                case "ID_desc":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderByDescending(s => s.CatalogID);
                    break;
                case "Ref":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderBy(s => s.Ref);
                    break;
                case "Ref_desc":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderByDescending(s => s.Ref);
                    break;
                case "ProdName":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderBy(s => s.ProductID);
                    break;
                case "ProdName_desc":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderByDescending(s => s.ProductID);
                    break;
                case "UnitPrice":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderBy(s => s.UnitPrice);
                    break;
                case "UnitPrice_desc":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderByDescending(s => s.UnitPrice);
                    break;
                case "Format":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderBy(s => s.Format);
                    break;
                case "Format_desc":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderByDescending(s => s.Format);
                    break;
                case "Quantity":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderBy(s => s.Quantity);
                    break;
                case "Quantity_desc":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderByDescending(s => s.Quantity);
                    break;
                case "Availability":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderBy(s => s.Availability);
                    break;
                case "Availability_desc":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderByDescending(s => s.Availability);
                    break;
                case "New":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderBy(s => s.New);
                    break;
                case "New_desc":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderByDescending(s => s.New);
                    break;
                case "Location":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderBy(s => s.Location);
                    break;
                case "Location_desc":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderByDescending(s => s.Location);
                    break;
                case "OrigNo":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderBy(s => s.OriginalNo);
                    break;
                case "OrigNo_desc":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderByDescending(s => s.OriginalNo);
                    break;
                case "Title":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderBy(s => s.Title);
                    break;
                case "Title_desc":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderByDescending(s => s.Title);
                    break;
                case "ShortTitle":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderBy(s => s.ShortTitle);
                    break;
                case "ShortTitle_desc":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderByDescending(s => s.ShortTitle);
                    break;
                case "Link":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderBy(s => s.Link);
                    break;
                case "Link_desc":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderByDescending(s => s.Link);
                    break;
                case "Notes":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderBy(s => s.Notes);
                    break;
                case "Notes_desc":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderByDescending(s => s.Notes);
                    break;
                case "Notes2":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderBy(s => s.Notes2);
                    break;
                case "Notes2_desc":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderByDescending(s => s.Notes2);
                    break;
                case "Type":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderBy(s => s.Type);
                    break;
                case "Type_desc":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderByDescending(s => s.Type);
                    break;
                case "SerTitle":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderBy(s => s.SeriesID);
                    break;
                case "SerTitle_desc":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderByDescending(s => s.SeriesID);
                    break;
                case "Subject":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderBy(s => s.Subject);
                    break;
                case "Subject_desc":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderByDescending(s => s.Subject);
                    break;
                case "ClassSubj":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderBy(s => s.ClassSubj);
                    break;
                case "ClassSubj_desc":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderByDescending(s => s.ClassSubj);
                    break;
                case "ClassGeog":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderBy(s => s.ClassGeog);
                    break;
                case "ClassGeog_desc":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderByDescending(s => s.ClassGeog);
                    break;
                case "ClassLang":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderBy(s => s.ClassLang);
                    break;
                case "ClassLang_desc":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderByDescending(s => s.ClassLang);
                    break;
                case "ClassDate":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderBy(s => s.ClassDate);
                    break;
                case "ClassDate_desc":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderByDescending(s => s.ClassDate);
                    break;
                case "RelName1":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderBy(s => s.RelatedNames1);
                    break;
                case "RelName1_desc":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderByDescending(s => s.RelatedNames1);
                    break;
                case "RelName2":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderBy(s => s.RelatedNames2);
                    break;
                case "RelName2_desc":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderByDescending(s => s.RelatedNames2);
                    break;
                case "RelName3":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderBy(s => s.RelatedNames3);
                    break;
                case "RelName3_desc":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderByDescending(s => s.RelatedNames3);
                    break;
                case "RelName4":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderBy(s => s.RelatedNames4);
                    break;
                case "RelName4_desc":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderByDescending(s => s.RelatedNames4);
                    break;
                case "RelTit1":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderBy(s => s.RelatedTitles1);
                    break;
                case "RelTit1_desc":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderByDescending(s => s.RelatedTitles1);
                    break;
                case "RelTit2":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderBy(s => s.RelatedTitles2);
                    break;
                case "RelTit2_desc":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderByDescending(s => s.RelatedTitles2);
                    break;
                case "RelTit3":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderBy(s => s.RelatedTitles3);
                    break;
                case "RelTit3_desc":
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderByDescending(s => s.RelatedTitles3);
                    break;
                default:
                    catalogs = catalogs.OrderBy(s => s.CatalogID);
                    break;
            }
            int pageSize = 10;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
            return View(catalogs.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
```

Catalog model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Microform_Intranet.Models
{
    public class Catalog
    {
        [Display(Name="Catalog ID")]
        public int CatalogID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Product")]
        public string Ref { get; set; }

        [Display(Name="Product Name")]
        [ForeignKey("Product2")]
        public string ProductID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name="Unit Price")]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
        public decimal? UnitPrice { get; set; }
        public string Format { get; set; }
        public string Quantity { get; set; }
        public string Availability { get; set; }
        public string New { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }

        [Display(Name="Original No.")]
        public string OriginalNo { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("RelatedTitle4")]
        public int? ShortTitle { get; set; }
        public string Link { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }

        [Display(Name="Notes 2")]
        public string Notes2 { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [Display(Name="Series Title")]
        public int? SeriesID { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("BicFull")]
        public string ClassSubj { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("BicFull2")]
        public string ClassGeog { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("BicFull3")]
        public string ClassLang { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("BicFull4")]
        public string ClassDate { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("RelatedName")]
        public int? RelatedNames1 { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("RelatedName2")]
        public int? RelatedNames2 { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("RelatedName3")]
        public int? RelatedNames3 { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("RelatedName4")]
        public int? RelatedNames4 { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("RelatedTitle")]
        public int? RelatedTitles1 { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("RelatedTitle2")]
        public int? RelatedTitles2 { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("RelatedTitle3")]
        public int? RelatedTitles3 { get; set; }

        public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
        public virtual Product Product2 { get; set; }
        public virtual Series Series { get; set; }
        public virtual BicFull BicFull { get; set; }
        public virtual BicFull BicFull2 { get; set; }
        public virtual BicFull BicFull3 { get; set; }
        public virtual BicFull BicFull4 { get; set; }
        public virtual RelatedName RelatedName { get; set; }
        public virtual RelatedName RelatedName2 { get; set; }
        public virtual RelatedName RelatedName3 { get; set; }
        public virtual RelatedName RelatedName4 { get; set; }
        public virtual RelatedTitle RelatedTitle { get; set; }
        public virtual RelatedTitle RelatedTitle2 { get; set; }
        public virtual RelatedTitle RelatedTitle3 { get; set; }
        public virtual RelatedTitle RelatedTitle4 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Catalog Index View:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<Microform_Intranet.Models.Catalog>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
<link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Catalog</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Catalog", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <p>
        Find by Ref, Product Name or Format: @Html.TextBox("searchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>
}
<div class="datatable" style="overflow-x:scroll">
    <table class="table" style="table-layout:fixed">
        <tr>
            <th style="width:90px">
                @Html.ActionLink("Catalog ID", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.IDSortParam, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            </th>
            <th style="width:125px">
                @Html.ActionLink("Ref", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.RefSortParam, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            </th>
            <th style="width:300px">
                @Html.ActionLink("Product Name", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.ProdNameSortParam, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            </th>
            <th style="width:100px">
                @Html.ActionLink("Unit Price", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.UnitPriceSortParam, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            </th>
            <th style="width:150px">
                @Html.ActionLink("Format", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.FormatSortParam, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            </th>
            <th style="width:75px">
                @Html.ActionLink("Quantity", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.QuantitySortParam, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            </th>
            <th style="width:150px">
                @Html.ActionLink("Availability", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.AvailabilitySortParam, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            </th>
            <th style="width:120px">
                @Html.ActionLink("New", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NewSortParam, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            </th>
            <th style="width:200px">
                @Html.ActionLink("Location", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.LocationSortParam, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            </th>
            <th style="width:150px">
                @Html.ActionLink("Original No.", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.OrigNoSortParam, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            </th>
            <th style="width:400px">
                @Html.ActionLink("Title", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.TitleSortParam, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            </th>
            <th style="width:300px">
                @Html.ActionLink("Short Title", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.ShortTitleSortParam, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            </th>
            <th style="width:350px">
                @Html.ActionLink("Link", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.LinkSortParam, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            </th>
            <th style="width:1000px">
                @Html.ActionLink("Notes", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NotesSortParam, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            </th>
            <th style="width:350px">
                @Html.ActionLink("Notes 2", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.Notes2SortParam, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            </th>
            <th style="width:150px">
                @Html.ActionLink("Type", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.TypeSortParam, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            </th>
            <th style="width:200px">
                @Html.ActionLink("Series Title", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.SerTitleSortParam, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            </th>
            <th style="width:200px">
                @Html.ActionLink("Subject", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.SubjectSortParam, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            </th>
            <th style="width:200px">
                @Html.ActionLink("Class Subject", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.ClassSubjSortParam, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            </th>
            <th style="width:300px">
                @Html.ActionLink("Class Geography", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.ClassGeogSortParam, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            </th>
            <th style="width:300px">
                @Html.ActionLink("Class Language", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.ClassLangSortParam, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            </th>
            <th style="width:200px">
                @Html.ActionLink("Class Date", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.ClassDateSortParam, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            </th>
            <th style="width:250px">
                @Html.ActionLink("Related Names 1", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.RelName1SortParam, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            </th>
            <th style="width:250px">
                @Html.ActionLink("Related Names 2", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.RelName2SortParam, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            </th>
            <th style="width:250px">
                @Html.ActionLink("Related Names 3", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.RelName3SortParam, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            </th>
            <th style="width:250px">
                @Html.ActionLink("Related Names 4", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.RelName4SortParam, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            </th>
            <th style="width:250px">
                @Html.ActionLink("Related Titles 1", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.RelTit1SortParam, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            </th>
            <th style="width:250px">
                @Html.ActionLink("Related Titles 2", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.RelTit2SortParam, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            </th>
            <th style="width:250px">
                @Html.ActionLink("Related Titles 3", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.RelTit3SortParam, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
            </th>
            <th style="width:150px"></th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CatalogID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product.ProductID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product2.ProductName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UnitPrice)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Format)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Quantity)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Availability)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.New)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Location)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OriginalNo)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RelatedTitle4.RelatedTitleName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Link)" target="_blank">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Link)</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Notes)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Notes2)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Type)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Series.SeriesName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Subject)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BicFull.BicFullName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BicFull2.BicFullName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BicFull3.BicFullName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BicFull4.BicFullName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RelatedName.RelatedNameName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RelatedName2.RelatedNameName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RelatedName3.RelatedNameName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RelatedName4.RelatedNameName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RelatedTitle.RelatedTitleName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RelatedTitle2.RelatedTitleName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RelatedTitle3.RelatedTitleName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.CatalogID }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.CatalogID }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.CatalogID })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>
</div>
<br />
Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount

@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
```

Comment: Could you clarify exactly where the problem is (i.e. where does your code fail or not behave as expected)? If feasible reducing the amount of code in your question would be good; try to provide only the code necessary to highlight/reproduce the problem.

Comment: It fails in the index view, for example where it says `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CatalogID)`, that displays just fine because it's displaying values directly from the table. however, in the next table row where it says `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product.ProductID)`, it's referencing the virtual Product declared in the model, and previously it would display the correct ProductID, but now it displays just a blank space.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check the relationship in database. If the relationship is present there then update your .edmx file after deleting all the contents. I think it will work.

Additional tip:- 
1. clean solution 
2. Rebuild solution

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned that what Approach you are using, (DB First or Code First)
in case of DB first just update your .edmx file and rebuild your Project, otherwise use migrations and update database. and it should re get that table from the database.